# React: Changing parent state not rendering child

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am extremely new to react and am building a simple todo list app. I am trying to edit data from my child component and send it back to my parent. When I am printing console logs the parent state seems to be getting set correctly, but the child elements are not refreshing. Am I doing something conceptually wrong here?

I have tried to share the entire code as I am not sure whether it is correct conceptually. I am new to JS. When the handleSave() and handleComplete() are called i can see correct values getting returned and set to my PArent State, but there is no refresh of the child components.

Below is my Parent class code.

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    taskList: [
    ]
  };

  saveEventHandler = data => {
    console.log("I am in saveEventHandler");
    var uniqid = Date.now();
    const taskList = [...this.state.taskList];
    taskList.push({
      id: uniqid,
      taskDescText: data,
      isFinished: false
    });
    console.log(taskList);
    this.setState({'taskList':taskList});
  };

  deleteEventHandler = (index) => {
    const taskList = [...this.state.taskList];
    taskList.splice(index,1)
    this.setState({'taskList':taskList});
  }

  editEventHandler = (index,data) => {
    var uniqid = Date.now();
    console.log("In edit event handler")
    console.log(data)
    console.log(index)
    const taskList = [...this.state.taskList];
    taskList[index] = {
      id: uniqid,
      taskDescText: data,
      isFinished: false
    }
    this.setState({'taskList':taskList});
   console.log(this.state.taskList)
  }

  handleComplete = (index) => {
    console.log("In complete event handler")
    const taskList = [...this.state.taskList];
    const taskDescriptionOnEditIndex = taskList[index]
    taskDescriptionOnEditIndex.isFinished = true
    taskList[index] = taskDescriptionOnEditIndex
    this.setState({'taskList':taskList});
    console.log(this.state.taskList)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>A Basic Task Listing App </h1>

        <CreateTask taskDescription={this.saveEventHandler} />
        {this.state.taskList.map((task, index) => {
          return (
            <Task
              taskDescText={task.taskDescText}
              taskCompleted={task.isFinished}
              deleteTask={() => this.deleteEventHandler(index)}
              editTask={(editTask) => this.editEventHandler(index,editTask)}
              handleComplete={() => this.handleComplete(index)}
              editing='false'
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

and my child class code

```
export default class  Task extends React.Component {
    state = {
        editing : false
    }
    notCompleted = {color: 'red'}
    completed = {color: 'green'}
    textInput = React.createRef();

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = props
      }

      handleEdit = () => {
        this.setState({editing:true});
      }

      handleSave = () => {
        this.props.editTask(this.textInput.current.value);
        this.setState({editing:false});

      };

    editingDiv = (<div className = 'DisplayTask'>
    <span className='TaskDisplayText' style={!this.props.taskCompleted ? this.notCompleted: this.completed}>{this.props.taskDescText} </span>
    <button label='Complete' className='TaskButton' onClick={this.props.handleComplete}> Complete</button>
    <button label='Edit' className='TaskButton' onClick={this.handleEdit}> Edit Task</button>
    <button label='Delete' className='TaskButton' onClick={this.props.deleteTask}> Delete Task</button>
    </div> );

    nonEditingDiv = ( <div className = 'DisplayTask'>
    <input className='TaskDescEditInput' ref={this.textInput}/>
    <button label='Save' className='TaskButton' onClick={this.handleSave} > Save Task</button>
    <button label='Delete' className='TaskButton' onClick={this.props.deleteTask}> Delete Task</button>
    </div>);

    render() {
    return (
    !this.state.editing ? this.editingDiv : this.nonEditingDiv
    )
};
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your `editingDiv` and `nonEditingDiv` definitions inside `render()` method. Since you're defining them as instance variables, they're initialized once, and never get re-rendered again with new prop values.

By moving them to `render()` method, `render()` which is called every time when there's a prop update will pick up the new prop values.

Comment: Happens all the time!